# Why cant i locate this xpath button?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

i try to click on a button via xpath with selenium but it wont work and i dont know why

it always says:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"the ways i wrote below"}

**the element shows up like this:**

```
<button class="dCJp8 afkep"><span aria-label="load comments" class="glyphsSpriteCircle_add__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7"></span></button>
```

```
#i already tried this ways: 
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[class='dCJp8 afkep']").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='load comments'").click()

#and i also tried it like this:
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li/div/button").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li/div/button").click()
#but everything wont work
```

**here is the code, if you guys want to try it yourself (line 13&14 for Login)**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
browser.get(url)

sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]").click()
#Login
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input").send_keys("Username")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[2]/div/label/input").send_keys("Password")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/button").click()
sleep(3)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div/div/button").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]").click()
url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CLMCNSenf-E/"
browser.get(url)

#try:
 #   browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li/div/button").click()
#except:
 #   browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li/div/button").click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='load comments'").click()
```

Comment: How many "load comments" button are on the page at one time? Can you add the ancestor elements for the `<button>`? We cannot determine the proper locator.

Comment: @GregBurghardt because of my less knowledge i dont really know what you mean. I switched my browser to englisch and it showed me instead of "load comments" "load more comments" so maybe that was the problem. Apart of that, one guy already found the solution for my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `xpath` seems wrong. attribute name should be starts-with `@`

Try below `xpath`

```
//button[@class='dCJp8 afkep']
```

Code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='dCJp8 afkep']").click()
```

Comment: Im so thankful, it worked. You saved me alot of hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
//button[./span[@aria-label='load comments']]
```

You could also use this as an xpath.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try an exception in your method

```
public static void clickCatchingStaleException(WebElement element) {

    try {
        element.click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
                    element.click();
    }
}
```

Or possibly click with actions

```
public static void clickWithActions(WebDriver wd, WebElement element) {
    Actions actions = new Actions(wd);
    actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:python]. Can you change your answer to use Python code?